# VB.NET: Force user to use the topmost form

Tags: vb.net, forms, minesweeper

I'm programming a Minesweeper clone in Visual Studio 2010, with VB.NET, as a Windows Form Application, and I'm having trouble with the Game Won and Game Lost forms. When I show those forms, I want the game form to still be visible, so that the player can see where the mines were, but I don't want the game form to be enabled until the Game Won or Game Lost form is closed. Exactly like Windows Minesweeper does when you win or lose.

There aren't any obvious properties for this, as far as I can see, and I've had no luck Googling, I don't know what terms to search.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the child form with [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) method to make it modal.

Comment: I get the error message "Form that is already visible cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Set the form's visible property to false before calling showDialog." whenever I try that, even though I set the form's visible property to False at 3 different points in the code, one directly before using showDialog.

Comment: @SiliconCelery, you should use the ShowDialog method to show the form and not on the current form.

Comment: Ah, I was doing "ShowDialog(frmGameLost)", as opposed to "frmGameLost.ShowDialog". It works perfectly now, thank you for your help.